# ring homomorphism of $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In which condition there exist ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ and how many are they ?

What I said is if there is homomorphism rings $f:\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, then necessarily $f(p)=pf(1)=p$ (and it's unique). Now $0=f(k)=k$ and thus $m\mid k$. I'm sure that we also must have $k\mid m$, but I don't know how to show it. My idea was to show that such an homomorphism must be one to one, but I didn't success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism then $f(1)=1$, hence
$$ f(n)=nf(1)=n $$
for all $n$. Therefore there can be at most one ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Moreover, we must have
$$ 0=f(0)=f(k\cdot 1)=k\cdot f(1)=k\cdot 1 $$
in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, so $f$ exists precisely when $m$ divides $k$.